Not enough space on external disk
I have a stick drive and I am trying to download Ubuntu onto it. The download says on the Ubuntu website says the file(s) will take up 5.8 GB however, after multiple attempts to download it onto my drive, I get a "disk full" error. The hard drive is supposed to be 114 GB so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. Any advice as to resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

That sounds like one of the fake chine thumb drives. Get a different brand and try again.

Please note downloading the Ubuntu installation (.ISO) file directly into a USB drive won't let you install Ubuntu from that drive. It is better to first download the file in your computer's download folder and then you will need to use a special application such as Ruffus (and the downloaded file) to create the Ubuntu installation USB. Just copying the file into the USB won't work. Here is the tutorial.

Your USB drive is probably formatted with FAT32, which can’t handle files larger than 4 GB. Since the Ubuntu ISO is bigger, you need to reformat your USB drive to exFAT or NTFS. To do this, right-click the drive, choose "Format," and select exFAT or NTFS. Check if there’s enough space on the drive. If you're making a bootable drive, use tools like Rufus or Balena Etcher. If it still doesn’t work, try a different USB stick or port. Its also possible that you have one of those fake thumb drives from China that don't work.

I changed the format of the disk to NTFS and it has worked. Thanks!
